# How do you sink() console output to your source() window?

Tags: r, output, rstudio

I know you can

```
sink("file_name.txt")
mean(c(1,2,3))
sink()
```

and expect a `2` in the `.txt` file. But how do I route this `2` to my source() window in Rstudio?

Answer (score 0):

[`sink()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/sink) works fine for me.

1. Open a file in the RStudio source pane.
2. In the console, sink to that file.

   ```
   sink("my_output.Rout", append = TRUE)
   ```
3. Type something in the console that generates output.

   ```
   sin(1:10)
   ```
4. Click in the file in the source pane to refresh it.
5. Content has appeared!
6. Close the sink when you are done.

   ```
   sink()
   ```

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for, which would be more the behavior of the history tab when you send `to source.` But also, I'm not able to recreate this result.  I have an R script called `testing.R` and am using `sink("testing.Rout", append = TRUE)`;
`sin(1:10)`;
`sink()`